# update data in the app after notification from server - even when force quitted?

Tags: ios, iphone

I do have a event-registration system where users can register online in a web app as well as an iOS app. The events are synced with the local calendar on the iPhone.

Now what I would like to achieve is that whenever the user changes something in the web app that it will automatically update the devices calendar. I tried push and background fetch, but both does not work when the user force quits the app. Is there any way to at least periodically run some code in the app to do an update?

Comment: There is workaround that you can use but your app will not be approved on the App Store - so only for internal/enterprise use

Comment: my app should be in the App Store so this is not really a solution then

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried Silent Notifications? You can include the `"content-available" : 1` key in your payload. iOS will wake your app and allow you to download some data.

Look under the `Configuring a Silent Notification` heading.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH10-SW1

Comment: This is the correct answer, **Apple Push Notification service**.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can achieve this with [PushKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit). It allows you to silently launch your app into the background with no visual alert prompt even your app was killed by swiping out from app switcher.

But the issue is PushKit is meant to be used for VoIP ,watchOS complications and  file provider updates only. I'm not sure if Apple allows us to use it for any other purpose.

So, if you couldn't do this with PushKit, there's no other way to achieve this.

Comment: Apple will not allow abuse of these.

Answer (score 1):

Use content-available in your payload without the alert key

```
  {
    "aps" = {
        "content-available" : 1
    };
    data = {
        "title" = "Welcome";
        };
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think silent push notifications will still be delivered and wake your app even if the user force quitted it. Note that push notifications in general are not guaranteed to be delivered though, so always to a sync when you app starts.

If silent push notifications do not work, then there is no way to do this though, as all the local event triggers (such as location updates) do not execute anymore when the user force quits the app.

The real solution here is probably to teach the user that force quitting does not optimize battery life, and in fact in many cases makes battery life even worse. This is a general misunderstanding and teaching the user to not do this does not only benefit yours but also other apps. So if your app relies on not being force quite, it may in deed be a solution to show an explanation screen to the user, explaining him that this harms the experience of the app.